# Input date in HTML dynamic table?

Tags: jquery, html

I know about jquery "date-picker" but cant understand how to implement it inside a **dynamic table** (one that appears once the user clicks on a google map and then they can select the date and finally click save.

one of my fields for the form is

```
"<tr><td>Name: </td> <td><input type='text' id='name'/> </td> </tr>" +
```

Id like a similar one but for date input inside of this dynamic table.

so far I have the relevant js and css files, but I think the script needs changing and also the actual field in the dynamic table.

any suggestions? the Jquery API is only for static tables, so is not useful for me.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by `the Jquery API is only for static tables`... jQuery is meant to handle all sorts of dynamic things

Comment: @PeterOlson. He meant that the input doesn't exist in the DOM ready event. Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you add that string to the DOM Call the `datePicker` function on it.

```
$('#buttonId').click(function(){
                    ... // Adding those elements with the name input somehow...
                    $('#name').datepicker();
                });
```